# CakePHP(2.5.1) Strange ErrorHandler / infinite-loop

Tags: php, cakephp

It is not only in 2.5.1 but in 2.7, in /lib/Cake/Error/ErrorHandler.php,

`handleException` calls `trigger_error` which calls `Error.handler = handleError` when `$error->render()` throws exception,

`handleError` calls `handleFatalError` when `$code = E_USER_ERROR`,

`handleFatalError` calls `$exceptionHandler` which is `Exception.handler = handleException`.

It seems that these function calls make an infinite-loop in some condition, and we suffered this in our project code. Is this an correct behavior? or is there any misunderstanding point (such as can justify an infinite-loop) ?

Thanks.

Comment: Oh, I found an message "Should be using configured ErrorHandler". is configuring default settings a correct solution? but it is strange that default settings don't work... :(

Comment: In my case, why `$error->render()` throws exception is probably an error in HtmlHelper.php. I don't know why that was editted in our sources from original, but I'm sure that throwing exception in `$error->render()` makes an infinite-loop.